# Ruby on Rails Adobe EchoSign SOAP Request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, soap, ruby-on-rails-2, echosign

I am trying to use Ruby on Rails to create a SOAP request to the [EchoSign API](https://secure.echosign.com/public/docs/EchoSignDocumentService16;jsessionid=4ECAD0D45A4714A14ADC9DF669BFB4DD.app12#RecipientInfo) but I am getting an error saying one of the fields is blank:

```
{http://dto14.api.echosign}RecipientRole: cannot accept ''
```

This is the code I am using:

```
require 'soap/wsdlDriver'
require 'base64'

filename = 'quote'
recipient = 'martin@domain.co.uk'
quote_id = params[:id]

$S = SOAP::WSDLDriverFactory.new("https://secure.echosign.com/services/EchoSignDocumentService16?wsdl").create_rpc_driver

r = $S.sendDocument(
  :apiKey => 'XXXXXXXXXXX',
  :senderInfo => SOAP::SOAPNil.new,         # we need to explicitly set elements to nil
  :documentCreationInfo => {
          :fileInfos  => [{
                  :file      => RAILS_ROOT + '/pdfs/' + quote_id + '.pdf',
                  :fileName  => filename,
          }],
          :recipients => 
                  [{ :RecipientInfo => [{
                                :email     => 'martin@domain.co.uk',
                                :fax       => SOAP::SOAPNil.new,
                                :role      => 'SIGNER' 
                  }]
          }],
          :message  => "This is neat.",
          :name     => "Test from SOAP-Lite: " + filename,
          :reminderFrequency => "WEEKLY_UNTIL_SIGNED",
          :signatureFlow => "SENDER_SIGNATURE_NOT_REQUIRED",
          :signatureType => "ESIGN",
          :callbackInfo => SOAP::SOAPNil.new,     # we need to explicitly set elements to nil
          :ccs => SOAP::SOAPNil.new,        # we need to explicitly set elements to nil
          :externalId => SOAP::SOAPNil.new,       # we need to explicitly set elements to nil
          :securityOptions => SOAP::SOAPNil.new,      # we need to explicitly set elements to nil
  }
)
```

There must obviously be something wrong with the way I am doing the

```
:recipients => 
              [{ :RecipientInfo => [{
                            :email     => 'martin@domain.co.uk',
                            :fax       => SOAP::SOAPNil.new,
                            :role      => 'SIGNER' 
              }]
}],
```

but I am finding it extremely difficult to find what just from the documentation, I think it will be something silly but can't spot it.

**update**

after looking more closely at the [example request](https://secure.echosign.com/static/apiv16/sampleXml/sendDocument-request.xml) I tried the following but it made no difference:

```
require 'soap/wsdlDriver'
require 'base64'

filename = 'quote'
quote_id = params[:id]

$S = SOAP::WSDLDriverFactory.new("https://secure.echosign.com/services/EchoSignDocumentService16?wsdl").create_rpc_driver

r = $S.sendDocument(
  :apiKey => 'XXXXXXXXXXX',
  :senderInfo => SOAP::SOAPNil.new,      
  :documentCreationInfo => {
          :fileInfos  => {
                  :FileInfo => {
                                :file      => RAILS_ROOT + '/pdfs/' + quote_id + '.pdf',
                                :fileName  => filename
                  }
          },
          :recipients => { 
                  :RecipientInfo => {
                                :email     => 'martin@domain.co.uk',
                                :fax       =>  SOAP::SOAPNil.new, 
                                :role      =>  'SIGNER'
                  }
          },
          :mergeFieldInfo => SOAP::SOAPNil.new,
          :tos => SOAP::SOAPNil.new,
          :message  => "This is neat.",
          :name     => "Test from SOAP-Lite: " + filename,
          :reminderFrequency => "WEEKLY_UNTIL_SIGNED",
          :signatureFlow => "SENDER_SIGNATURE_NOT_REQUIRED",
          :signatureType => "ESIGN",
          :callbackInfo => SOAP::SOAPNil.new,     # we need to explicitly set elements to nil
          :ccs => SOAP::SOAPNil.new,        # we need to explicitly set elements to nil
          :externalId => SOAP::SOAPNil.new,       # we need to explicitly set elements to nil
          :securityOptions => SOAP::SOAPNil.new     # we need to explicitly set elements to nil
  }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try to pass the value `SIGNER`  with double quotations like `"SIGNER"`. Just like you have for `"ESIGN"` and some other parameters.

Also, if sending for `ESIGN`, `Fax` should not need to be `nil` . Try to not defining `:Fax` at all.

Answer (score -1):

You should change the email address and the role to have double quotes instead of single quotes.

```
              :RecipientInfo => {
                            :email     => "martin@domain.co.uk",
                            :fax       =>  SOAP::SOAPNil.new, 
                            :role      =>  "SIGNER" change
```

Same as you have done for 
:reminderFrequency => "WEEKLY_UNTIL_SIGNED",
:signatureFlow => "SENDER_SIGNATURE_NOT_REQUIRED",